# Avoid trigger Bitbucket pipeline when the title starts with Draft or WIP

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

To automate our CI process, I need run the Bitbucket pipelines only when the title not starts with "Draft" or "WIP". Atlassian has only this features https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-glob-patterns-on-the-pipelines-yaml-file/.

I tried with the regex `^(?!Draft:|WIP:).+` like this:

```yaml
pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    '^(?!Draft:|WIP:).+':
      - step:
          name: Tests
```

but the pipeline not start under any circumstances (with or withour Draft:/WIP:). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Note the PR pattern you define in the pipelines is matched against the source branch, not the PR title. Precisely, I used to feature an empty pipeline for PRs from `wip/*` branches, e.g.

```
pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    wip/*:
      - step:
          name: Pass
          script:
            - exit 0
    "**":
      - step:
          name: Tests
          # ...
```

But this workflow requires you to work on `wip/*` branches and changing their source branch later on. This is somewhat cumbersome and developers just did not opt-in.

This works, though.

Comment: You are right, my bad. I do not pay attention on this detail.